# Enable Location Services via command line in OSX 10.10

Tags: macos, command-line, osx-yosemite

How can I enable Location Services from the command line in OSX 10.10?

I searched the web and was able to find some stuff on 10.7 but does't seem to work in 10.10:

```
launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locationd.plistdefaults write /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locationd Disabled -bool false
```

launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locationd.plist

Also, is there a command-line way to add applications to the list of apps allowed to access your location?

Comment: I am curious about this as well - I am currently doing some testing within terminal to see if there is a way to force enable this - It looks like the information for Location Services is stored inside the locationd clients.plist file in var/db/locationd/ - I will report back if I find anything useful

Comment: Further to Mikes comment: I did a bit of digging and the list of enabled apps can be found here: `defaults read /var/db/locationd/clients.plist`. The plist to enable location services is here: `defaults read /var/db/locationd/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.locationd.[hardware UUID]` LocationServicesEnabled You can get the Hardware UUID by using: `/usr/sbin/system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | grep "Hardware UUID"`